# Recoiljs with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, recoiljs

Im trying to make a complex state management, excel like in a react app that actually uses redux, and trying to implement the state management with redux is actually much more complex, but i already have most of the front structure done with redux, is there a way to implement recoiljs and use it with redux? like using both global state managers at the same time, I tried searching in the internet but couldn't find info about using both state managers at the same time

Comment: They are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no info because there is no complication to it - just do it. It works exactly like just using one or using the other - just at the same time. There is nothing you have to do to hook them up with each other - they have no idea about each other and just work side by side.